# Как сделать слушать выбор пунктов меню в DrawerLayout?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Ситуация вроде кажется и простая, но я не могу понять. Смотрите есть стандартное приложение со шторкой DrawerLayout Там в шторку подсунут список из меню. За этим списком из меню закреплена навигация. Когда нажимаешь на элемент списка переключается фрагмент. Но мне надо чтобы как минимум 2 элемента списка не переключали фрагмент, но я не знаю как их отследить если поставить `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` то рушится навигация по фрагментам пробовал в NavigationItemSelectedListener переключать, но почему то не переключаются а друг на друга ложаться.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
           /* case R.id.nav_home: {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, new HomeFragment(), "nav_home").commit();
            }
            case R.id.nav_gallery: {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, new GalleryFragment(), "nav_gallery").commit();
            }
            case R.id.nav_slideshow: {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, new SlideshowFragment(), "nav_slideshow").commit();
            }*/
            case R.id.nav_upd: {
                //do somthing
                L.i("Update");
                break;
            }
            case R.id.nav_exit: {
                L.i("Exit");
                break;
            }
        }
        //binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        //close navigation drawer
//        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как насчет отключения через менюшку DrawerLayout так например:

```
NavigationView navigationView= findViewById(R.id.nav_id_in_layout)

Menu menuNav=navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem nav_item2 = menuNav.findItem(R.id.nav_item2);
nav_item2.setEnabled(false)
```

также вот [статья хорошая](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer) про работу с данным видом навигации

Comment: Спасибо сейчас почитаю. Проклятый андроид ничего нормально не продумали все через одно место.

Comment: ну так то да) но вообще думаю вам через меню нужно отключать в идеальном варианте как мне кажется)

Comment: Не совсем понял про отключения, но благодаря вам догадался вот такую штуку поставить, еще раз спасибо: MenuItem navExit = menuNav.findItem(R.id.nav_exit); navExit.setOnMenuItemClickListener    В принципе хватает.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галку слева от него.